nftables: Filter on interface and ip block?
This does not work (via systemd restart nftables, which should load /etc/nftables.conf):
cat /etc/nftables.d/forward/example.conf

meta oifname "eth2" ip daddr 5.6.7.8/30 accept
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ~~~~
Error: Statement after terminal statement has no effect

But this also does not work:
ip daddr 5.6.7.8/30 meta oifname "eth2" accept
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ~~~~
Error: Statement after terminal statement has no effect

Neither does this (using a concatenation example)
ip daddr . meta oifname {5.6.7.8/30 . "eth2"} accept
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Statement after terminal statement has no effect

Note: Contents of /etc/nftables.conf:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter;
                include "/etc/nftables.d/forward/*.conf"
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter;
        }
}

How do I do both, which would be necessary if this ip range isn't always routed to eth2 (policy routes, for example), and eth2 doesn't just contain this ip range?

Please edit your post to show full rule including table and chain. interface names does not need to be quoted btw.

"This does not work." That exact rule works without any errors when I run it as nft add rule filter output meta oifname "eth2" ip daddr 5.6.7.8/30 accept. This presumes that there exists a table named filter and a chain named output.

I found the problem (finally). DOS line endings. I had not fixed all the files and tried different notations found in guides (which were wrong).
/r/n is invisible, but /r is of course a symbol 'before' the line ending. nftables doesn't like /r and tries to read it as a syntax symbol, then complains that there's 'something extra' after the end of the rule.
